# Search for Oracle SQL grammar

Tags: sql, oracle, parsing

Can anyone give me a link to Oracle SQL grammar, please?

By grammar, I mean *yacc* or *antlr* sources that can help me.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may find your need in the official documentation of oracle [for example](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2066611)

Answer (score 5):

[Here's a set of grammars](http://antlr3.org/grammar/list.html) for ANTLR, including 2 Oracle 11g SQL grammars.

Answer (score 3):

```
http://www.antlr.org/grammar/ORACLE-7-SQL
http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list
http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1209225566284/PLSQL3.g
```

Comment: All of these links got to 404 pages.