# runtime 'intellisense' for ANTLR grammars

Tags: c#, wpf, autocomplete, antlr

I spent most of today attempting to create a grammar for a SQL 'where' clause. I then found a helpful article here [Search for Oracle SQL grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346235/search-for-oracle-sql-grammar) which should take care of that part of my task.

So that leads to my question -

Given an ANTLR grammar, and a WPF textbox that a user is typing into, is it possible to have a VS-like Intellisense that 'hints' at the possible values that a user can type, that would not 'break' the current typed expression?

A very simple example would be if I defined a grammar as '[columnName]' operator value, once the user types in the last character of the column name and a space, then the list of operators defined in the grammar will pop up.

Sorry if that is confusing. Thank you.

Comment: I doubt you can generate this from a grammar alone. A top-down grammar can maybe kinda sorta tell you what constructs are allowed at the current editing point, but it's probably not sufficient if the autocompletion suggests the user type "an expression" or something else that is left for a later pass to process.